# Process.Start, WorkingDirectory, start one exe from another

Tags: c#, process.start, working-directory

I hope you will get my problem, dont know if I can describe it properly in english, but I will try :)

Situation:

- Folder Structure: MainFolder/Sub1/Sub2
- 2 exe files: MainFolder/MainProg.exe and /Sub2/SecondProg.exe
- MainProg.exe is not from me, I wrote an .cs file inside /Sub1, kind of a plugin. (I think MainProg.exe kind of works like a compiler, cause it has a log window where I can see errors from my .cs file.. I think the author somewhere mentioned a JIT compiler ?!)
- Start MainProg.exe -> Click a button -> Start SecondProg.exe
- SecondProg.exe reads values from an xml file
- Both are .NET 4.5

Problem:

- I want to have the xml file inside /Sub2
- If I do that and start SecondProg.exe the normal way, double clicking it, everything is working fine
- If I try to start SecondProg.exe via the button in MainProg.exe, I get "SecondProg is not working anymore" from windows.
- If I copy the xml file to MainFolder, its working..

So, I am still learning C#, but could there be a problem with the workingdirectory? I am so confused, because the MainProg.exe has nothing to do with my xml file, it doesnt even know its there, the only point, where I use it is when loading values into SecondProg.exe...

Inside my .cs file, I start the SecondProg via

```
public override void Button()
{
Process.Start("Sub1\\Sub2\\SecondProg.exe");
}
```

So its like, MainProg has the button, in my .cs file I tell him what to onClick.
well.. its hard to describe if you're not using your native language, but I hope you get what I mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SecondProg.exe apparently looks in its working directory for that file and fails if it doesn't find it.  As such, you have to set the working directory of the new process.  To do that, create a `ProcessStartInfo` object, set the `FileName` to the path of the EXE file and the `WorkingDirectory` to the path of the folder containing that EXE.  You then pass that object as an argument when you call `Process.Start`.

Comment: like this? http://pastebin.com/72xzUKDs 
thats not working for me... no more error, but it just doesnt start.. (also without last \\ in WorkingDirectory).. I think the Problem is, SecondProg.exe is uning the WorkingDirectory of MainProg.exe for what ever reason...

Comment: tried to edit the path to xml inside SecondProg.exe to Sub1\\Sub2\\file.xml but thats not working, no error, just doesnt do anything.. can I maybe change the workingdirectory of SecondProg.exe directly in its sourcecode?? cause thats the one i can change code of

Comment: Isn't the XML file in the same folder as SecondProg.exe?  That's what your original question says.  If so then you might try doing what I actually said, i.e. set the `WorkingDirectory` to the path of the folder containing SecondProg.exe.  That's exactly what happens when you double-click an EXE file so if that works then it would seem that that is what you should be doing, which is why I said to do that in the first place.

Comment: thats what i did, the problem is, MainProg.exe seems to override the workingdirectory of SecondProg.exe from "Sub1/Sub2/" to "MainFolder".

I can fix it by editing the path to xml file inside the source of SecondProg.exe. so, if I do "Sub1/Sub2/file.xml" instead of "file.xml" its working